# Matching anything in Spring RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, request-mapping

On Spring MVC rest service I am having issues trying to match anything that is beyond my configured RequestMapping value.

So for e.g. I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{configKey}/{arguments:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Which says that match anything that is beyond the second path variable. The problem is that this e.g. works ok with:

```
get("/test/document")
```

while this ends up with 404:

```
get("/test/document/download")
```

It is weird that Spring can't handle this regex. I actually tried a lot of solutions, but none of them worked.

Previously I had this configuration on JAX-RS:

```
@Path("/{configKey}/{arguments:.*}")
```

And everything was good, but now I am migrating and having this issue.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Adding `{configKey}/**` - doesn't work

Adding `{configKey}/{arguments}/**` works, but for e.g. if I call:

`get("/test/document/download")` I get only `test` as my config key and `document` as arguments. In the arguments I expect to get all what's beyond the `{configKey}`. Which can be anything for e.g. it should work in any case:

```
get("/test/document")
get("/test/document/download")
get("/test/document/download/1")
get("/test/document/download/1/2")
get("/test/whatever/xxx/1/2/etc")
```

Which was working with config for JAX-RS: `@Path("/{configKey}/{arguments:.*}")`

Comment: How many arguments to you expect? Do you know the exact number?

Comment: No, that's the point, it's dynamic and can be any number of arguments.

Comment: What do you want bound to `arguments`?

Comment: Could you try to change it to @RequestMapping(value = "{configKey}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET) ?

Comment: sorry Patrick, wouldn't answer if I saw your comment on time, we can even swap, you answer, I delete :)

Comment: I've edited my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to it, it's not the permanent solution, I think it's a bug in Spring and I raised a [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12737), but until it's fixed here it is:

I had to define my request mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{configKey}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

So basically match all what's after first variable in a path.

Then:

```
String arguments = pathMatcher.extractPathWithinPattern(
        request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE).toString(),
        request.getPathInfo());
```

Where a pathMatcher is an instance of AntPathMatcher used by Spring.

So now calling HTTP GET on for e.g. this path:

```
get("/test/leaderboard/user/mq/frankie1")
```

I have:

```
configKey = test
arguments = leaderboard/user/mq/frankie1
```

Comment: This jira is marked "Works as Designed", "Path variables in an @RequestMapping pattern cannot span multiple path segments.". So I think we cannot solve this problem, but to use query parameters instead.

Answer (score 2):

The following mapping should work for you

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{configKey}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

This mapping is known as [default mapping pattern](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-pattern-comparison).

Comment: This doesn't work and as I mentioned it won't bind the rest what's beyond {configKey} to {arguments} path variable.

Answer (score -1):

Spring Use AntPathMatcher, The mapping matches URLs using the following rules:

```
1. ? matches one character
2. * matches zero or more characters
3. ** matches zero or more 'directories' in a path
```

This is how I configure request mapping url, I've test in my computer, and it works and You can custom based on your needs.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new-ajax/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Test case

```
/new-ajax/document/1
/new-ajax/document/download/1
/new-ajax/document/download/1/2
/new-ajax/test/whatever/xxx/1/2/etc
```